# Vertex Paint Paint Mask does not work anymore

Tags: vertex-paint

I'm asking this question again since my first post did not get any answers anymore and my question is still open:

I'm using the current basic steam version of blender and want to use vertex paint with the paint mask feature, so the color stops at the edge of each face and does not " bleed " over to the next faces.

It suddenly stopped working since Blender 3.5
I made a little video directly showing the problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HFmBEVjcJ5U

Can you please help me somehow get it working again?
Essentially this:

[image: problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the color attribute in the *Vertex* domain but actually, **you want to use the *Face Corner* domain**.

With a *Vertex* color you can only paint the vertices, similar to *Weight* painting. There is no info stored for the faces.

If you create a *Face Corner* color then Blender knows which corner of the face you want to colorize. It knows face #5 is defined by vertices #10, #11, #12, and #13, and vertice #10 is green while the other ones are blue for exactly this face.

[image: vertex color vs face corner color]

Note: In the *Geometry Nodes* spreadsheet, you can check the domains. If you select one you will see the vertices or face corners and their color attribute, respectively.

Comment: Thank you a thousand times for your time investment to make that picture and for the explanation. It now works properly :)